# The file with the .gpx extension can not be loaded via Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, mime-types, gpx, storage-access-framework

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) that the MIME-type of the GPX files is `application/gpx+xml`. So I used the following code:

```
startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("application/gpx"),
        READ_GPX_FILE_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

Also tried this one:

```
startActivityForResult(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("application/gpx+xml"),
        READ_GPX_FILE_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

And as a last resort I tried to use `Intent#setTypeAndNormalize(String)` method. No luck - when the file picker dialog starts, all the files with `.gpx` extension have the grey color, i.e. they aren't selectable. Is there some issue in my code, or the SAF's `Intent` have some set of preconfigured mime-types which it can use and `application/gpx+xml` does not belong to this set?

Comment: `"*/*"` will do it.

Comment: @greenapps yes, but in that case I have to write the extra code to check the mime-type of the selected file to make sure the app does not crash when the user accidentally selects audio file instead of gpx file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to the document provider to determine the MIME types of the documents that it provides. For some document providers, they may know document MIME types from upstream sources (e.g., an email client that offers a document provider might take the MIME types of attachments from the MIME headers of the email). For everything else, they will tend to rely upon `MimeTypeMap`, which in turn relies on an internal class named `MimeUtils`.

And `MimeUtils` has nothing for GPX, [at least through Android 7.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-7.0.0_r6/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java).

So, you would need to take greenapps' suggestion, use `*/*`, and be prepared to deal with parsing errors.

FWIW, I filed [a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222779) to get GPX added to `MimeUtils`.